# Why does Namecheap keep sending me a message that says "The AutoSSL certificate renewal may cause a reduction of coverage"

Tags: web-hosting, https, cpanel, security-certificate, namecheap

I'm working on a client's website that was set up by someone else. It's hosted by Namecheap and we have access to cPanel.

The client is apparently receiving this email message twice a day (I've replaced their domain name with example.com):

> [example.com] ⚠ example.com: The AutoSSL certificate renewal may cause a reduction of coverage on 2017-11-28 at 00:00:00 UTC
>
> The “cPanel” AutoSSL provider could not renew the SSL certificate without a reduction of coverage because of the following problem:
>
> The system failed to fetch the DCV (Domain Control Validation) file at `http://example.com/.well-known/pki-validation/(long string of letters and numbers).txt` because of an error: The system failed to send an HTTP (Hypertext Transfer Protocol) “GET” request to `http://example.com/.well-known/pki-validation/(long string of letters and numbers).txt` because of an error: Size of response body exceeds the maximum allowed of 16384
>
> The domain “example.com” resolved to an IP address “(the IP address of our website)” that does not exist on this server.

I've been Googling around but there doesn't seem to be much about this. I looked through the "SSL/TLS Manager" section of cPanel but it appears to be blank. They've been using HTTP this whole time so it doesn't seem like it would be a case of an SSL certificate expiring.

What could be causing this kind of error and what kind of steps should I take next?

Comment: [This page](https://www.agics.nl/News.php?ID=1131) (Translated from Dutch) appears to suggest that this is due to an (erroneous) "automatic update of cPanel"?!

Comment: This question seems related: https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/107290/using-autossl-letsencrypt-to-give-cert-to-subdomain-pointing-to-separate-server

Answer (score 1):

I have a client who was receiving this daily from Godaddy. I have also seen this happen numerous times as other registrars. When I called godaddy, I was told that tHe solution is to purchase the SSL certificate from the same "registrar/host" that is used for hosting the website.

I'm sure there is a more straight forward way to fix this issue, but it worked for me.

Comment: The shorter solution would be to solve the HTTP problem you list, which means having more details on how the automated certificate renewal works.

Answer (score 0):

> Size of response body exceeds the maximum allowed of 16384

The error message does say that your txt file is larger than the amount of characters permitted. I would start from there. Is it possible to correct the file size of that .txt file and keep it under the character limit requirement?